# setting breakpoints when array value changes in cuda-gdb

Tags: c++, gdb, cuda

Is there a way to set a breakpoint in GDB for when a particular index of an array changes?

That is, can I make it stop when array[25] changes? This would be happening in the kernel, of course.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about watchpoints:  `watch array[25]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it follows the same commands as gdb, the command would be something like `watch array[25]`

Edit: As of September 2010 watchpoints were not implemented, and you need a watchpoint to do this. http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=180367

Comment: @null-set No love for nsight?

Comment: @Gaurav I wasn't aware of that. Derek did ask specifically about gdb, but it is useful to know about an alternative that apparently does support watchpoints.

Answer (score 1):

You may use http://developer.nvidia.com/object/nsight.html for debugging purposes.